# how to limit dma address to specific range in linux kernel?

Tags: kernel, memory

I want to limit the dma address the device can access to 0x0100_0000~0x03ff_ffff.
But I don't know how to set the `dma_mask` and `coherent_dma_mask`.

It's easy to set the "dma mask" for a range start from 0.

Can anybody help about this?

Comment: I am not completely following the contents in this link, but it should get you started. http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-4

Comment: Thanks, I've read this article before, but I can't find how to limit the address.

Comment: I'd be interested in understanding the underlying issue here and what specific problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: finally I got to know that there's no need to limit the address range, `0x0100_0000~0x03ff_ffff` is where SDRAM mapped to, all master on the bus can see this range, and dma alloc coherent will not go out of this range. @Ramesh @mdpc